# React Material-UI Modal close only on ESC key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a problem with a Modal element from Material-UI package. Closing modal is only working by pressing the ESC key. What I would like to achieve is closing by using button and by click in the backdrop.
I'm testing it on lastest version of Chromium for Linux if that matters.

Here is code from my EventContainer.js file.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './EventContainer.css';
import Modal from '@material-ui/core/Modal';
import Map from '../Map/Map';

class eventContainer extends Component {

  constructor(){
    super();
    this.showEvent = this.showEventHandler.bind(this);
    this.closePreviewHandler = this.closePreviewHandler.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      modalIsOpen: false,
      open: false
    };
  }

  showEventHandler = () => {
    this.setState ({
      open: true,
      modalIsOpen: !this.state.modalIsOpen
    });
  }

  closePreviewHandler = () => {
    this.setState ({
      open: false
    });
  }

  render(){
    return (
    <div className="event-container" onClose={this.showEventHandler}>
      <img className="event-container__image" src={this.props.img} alt="default"/>
      <div className="event-container__date">
        <time className="time-container">{this.props.date}</time>
        <time className="time-container">{this.props.time}</time>
      </div>
      <h2 className="event-container__title">{this.props.title}</h2>
      <div className="event-container__meta"> 
        <p>{this.props.host}</p>
        <strong>{this.props.localization}</strong>
      </div>
      <span className="event-container__category"> {this.props.category}</span>
      <Modal
        aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
        open={this.state.open}
        onClose={this.closePreviewHandler}
        onBackdropClick={this.closePreviewHandler}
        >
          <div className="event-preview">
            <h2 className="event-preview__title">{this.props.title}</h2>
            <img src={this.props.img} alt=""/>
            <div className="event-container__date">
              <time className="time-container">{this.props.date}</time>
              <time className="time-container">{this.props.time}</time>
            </div>
            <div className="event-container__meta">
              <p className="event-container__host">{this.props.host}</p>
              <strong className="event-container__localization">{this.props.localization}</strong>
            </div>
            <p className="event-description">{this.props.description}</p>
            <Map/>
            <button className="event-preview__close" onClick={this.closePreviewHandler}>close</button>
          </div>
      </Modal>
    </div>

    );
  }

}

export default eventContainer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this.showEventHandler bound to an onClose function. While this is not necessarily incorrect, it does seem like an anti-pattern, and I woulnd't be surprised if this was an issue. Typically, a modal appears *on top of* whatever else you have open. Try removing that and reporting back.

Comment: Now I can't close the modal using any of 3 methods(ESC key, backdrop click, click on close button). Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just seeing this now but I figured out what might be going wrong! Let's say you are using ReactJS, if you have a functional component, you need to make sure the Modal is outside of the div you want it to pop out over. This should allow you to have your  element but the Modal goes outside and around the app. Then if you click outside of the Modal, it falls back to the  element.

**For example:**

```
import React from 'react'
import Modal from '@mui/material/Modal';

const react = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Modal />
            <div>
            
            </div>
        </>
        )
}

export default react
```

Hope this helps anyone building a Modal

Comment: Modal uses a portal so this is not correct.
when you popup the model, it actually renders outside of root.

Comment: Worked for me My modal was inside a ```<Button>``` Component removing it outside it solved it!